Three things that women die for during childbirth
In the 2nd Perek of Shabbat, the Mishnah says that women die during childbirth on account of 3 things: not being careful with Niddah, Challah, and Candle Lighting.
Of course, many Jews nowadays don’t keep these (especially Niddah) yet don’t die during childbirth. Do any commentaries give a non-literal interpretation to this piece of aggadata?

Some do die during child birth rl

is it saying that a woman dies because of this, or that if she dies, it could be traced to one of these causes (or contributing causes).

@rosends but it says בשעת לדתן

Hashem gave people the chochmah to invent medical treatments that make death in childbirth far less common.

@NoachMiFrankfurt yes, hence my question of how we interpret this Chazal nowadays which seems almost inapplicable…

Plenty of people drive drunk (lo aleinu) and make it home just fine. The vast majority of drunk drivers, actually. So why do we say drunk driving is deadly?

I remember asking this question, but, anyway, it should be read "after a [Jewish] woman died during childbirth, it can be retrospectively attributed to the three transgressions", not "those three transgressions cause death at birth".

In general, Rabbinic statements are apologetic rather than predictive. They only provide speculatory "explanations" after things happen.

@AlBerko I like that

I did not see such nonliteral commentary. It appears that the mishna is formulated in a way which is psychologically attuned to women to provide a message similar to the one we have in the beginning of Sh'ma. It is not abstract, but specific and focuses on mitzvos which express similar ideas. I.e. it yields inductive reasoning (prat uklal) rather than deductive (klal uprat).

The prohibition of niddah is similar to loving G-d בְּכָל־לְבָבְךָ֥, with one's heart, i.e. one's body. That is to leave personal physical comfort for a higher chance to create life.

The mitzvah of challah is similar to loving G-d בְּכָל־מְאֹדֶֽךָ with physical resources. I.e. also giving property for holy purpose.

Finally, Shabbos candles is similar to loving G-d בְּכָל־נַפְשְׁךָ֖ with entire soul, i.e. spiritual purpose.


Each of these 3 mitzvos, when violated may lead to kares or punishments leading to death, which may have influenced the ending of the mishna. It was formulated, when maternal mortality rates were high.
I think even switching of the order is important in carrying the message for a woman, vs. what men read in Sh'ma: בְּכָל־לְבָבְךָ֥ וּבְכָל־נַפְשְׁךָ֖ וּבְכָל־מְאֹדֶֽךָ, which is inline with Mishna Sota 3:4, etc.

+1 for creativity!

+1 Not fully satisfied but definitely an interesting take

@AlBerko Thank you.

@CuriousYid Thank you.
